# Why g++/clang do not support std::basic_string<T>::replace with const_iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang, stdstring

As I've found in the latest standard draft and on cppreference.com [`std::basic_string<T>::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) could be called with `const_iterator`s as its arguments (for example in its second form where part of the string is replaced by other string) and there is even no indication that it was changed in C++11/14

However as I see g++/clang++ even their latest stable versions refuse to compile the following code:

```
#include <string>

void f () {
   std::string test = "testtt";
   test.replace (test.cbegin (), test.cend (), "omg");
}
```

So my question is: Am I missing something and my example is wrong somehow? Have standard changed in that regard? Or is it compiler standard libraries fault?

Comment: could you attach the output of the compiler, please?

Comment: clang with libc++ [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5795353ffe1c7c4) your code successfully, so it looks like something libstdc++ missed. Please file a bug report (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/)

Comment: @Praetorian oh I thought clang uses libc++ by default so it surpised me, probably I should just file a bug report to libstdc++ then.

Comment: This is already fixed for GCC 5. N.B. this was changed for C++11, in C++03 `basic_string::replace` only took non-const iterators.

Comment: @JonathanWakelyn It's great that it was fixed, I guess I would have to use a workaround for now because GCC 5 is not quite yet stable version.